# Extracting part of current page's URL in javascript

Tags: javascript

In ASP.NET MVC 3 site, I open the following uri

```
http://myserver/incidents/supercompany/register
```

That page needs to make use of ajax JSON retrieval mechanism with the help of jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('/Incidents/[[COMPANY NAME GOES HERE]]/SearchPeople/' + request.term, function (data)
```

I am new to javascript. How can I obtain `supercompany` part of my current url to build the

`/Incidents/supercompany/SearchPeople/` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your URLs follow a logical structure, you can do this

```
var URLparts = window.location.toString().substr(7).split('/');
```

And you can now access `URLparts[1]` to get the company name. Obviously, you need to be able to know that that will ALWAYS be there, but it's a solution if you can guarantee that (eg. with htaccess).

Comment: When a Chrome JS debugger aproaches this line, it just jumps out of subroutine execution. May it have something to do with the fact that the code is being executed from a linked js file, or, perhaps, with the fact, that I call this code as a part of `source: function` of jQuery .autocomplete?

Comment: Err... maybe? :) Just had a quick look back over this and I've seen that I forgot to put `.toString()` in after the `.location`, updating answer with that now. It may fix your issue.

Comment: Yep, or do as I did - use pathname: `URLparts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
                $.getJSON('/Incidents/' + URLparts[2] + '/SearchPeople/'`